# can i use percentage instead of number in LIMIT clause

Tags: postgresql, limit

[image]

how can I select 50% of a table in psql

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

Your LIMIT doesn't use an `order by`, so apparently you don't care *which* 50% you get.

If my assumption is true, you can achieve that using the [`tablesample`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) option:

```
select *
from worker tablesample system (50);
```

If you want "more random" but slower result, you can use `tablesample bernoulli (50)` instead.